# Angular 5, Route not working in layout, whereas parent is working

Tags: angular5, angular-routing

routing in layout module:-

```
{ path: 'userlogin', component: UserloginComponent }
```

parent routing in app.routing

```
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: UserLayoutComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',  
  }
```

whenever i call it with /userlogin this url, it every time gives error saying that this Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'userlogin'

Comment: use redirectTo as redirectTo: 'useLogin' jt try it

Comment: i did this
 {
    path: 'login',
    //component: UserLayoutComponent,
    redirectTo: 'userlogin',
    pathMatch: 'full',  
  }

and it says Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login'

Comment: can you share your entire app.routing